# Can I know the cohomology of a group by knowing the cohomology of its composition factors?

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Suppose $A$ is a $G$-module. And suppose $G$ has two composition factors, $N_1$ and $N_2$. Then we can examine the left-exact functors $(-)^{N_1}$ and $(-)^{N_2}$ and conclude that their composition gives $(-)^G$ and plugging them into the Grothendieck spectral sequence we get the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence as follows:
$$H^p(N_1,H^q(N_2,A))\implies H^{p+q}(G, A)$$ I am not making too much fuss about how the composition factors clunk together. Now I see an obvious extension of this idea by introducing more composition factors. Suppose $G$ is some arbitrary finite group whose factors are $N_1, \dots,N_n$. If I let $F_k$ denote the functor $(-)^{N_k}$ then in the language of derived categories, the total right derived functor of a composition $F_1\circ F_2\circ \cdots \circ F_k$ should be $RF_1\circ RF_2 \circ \cdots \circ RF_k$.

So in my mind, if you can decompose a group $G$ into composition factors, and you know enough information about how to put them back together to give $G$ again, then you should in theory be able to determine the group cohomology of $G$ with coefficients in some $G$-module $A$. So my assumption is that the diffierentials you would get in a spectral sequence of some multicomplex would really only depend on the information about how $G$ is put together and how it interacts with $A$.

In the bigger picture this would mean that knowing the group cohomology of finite simple groups and information about group extensions is the only information needed to work out the group cohomology of some finite group. I would presume, however, that even though this information is there, it is really inaccessible and makes this whole process really pointless.

Comment: What is your question? Perhaps there is a more focussed question here, about what the analogue of the Grothendieck spectral sequence for a composition of more than two functors should be?

Comment: Finite $p$-groups are a good illustration that the answer to the question is simply "no". The composition factors are cyclic groups, but the information needed to build is too complex. There are no general-purpose formulas for the higher differentials in the spectral sequence, so it's not even clear what information from the group extension is needed. This is why the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence isn't the tool of choice for computations of cohomology of finite $p$-groups

Comment: @MatthiasWendt what are the tools of computations of cohomology of finite p-groups?

Comment: For one thing, it's important to keep track of the multiplicative structure. This reduces complexity because as algebra the cohomology is finitely generated while it's not finitely generated as module. Second, instead of computing differentials, one actually tries to construct a projective resolution of the coefficients over the group ring. Then one uses criteria when these actually compute group cohomology. This may employ detection of cohomology classes on elementary abelian subgroups. There is also a lot of commutative algebra involved in figuring out generators for the ring structure...

Comment: Have a look at http://users.minet.uni-jena.de/cohomology/ for more. This is not to say that the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence doesn't play a role, but there are a lot of other tools necessary to actually extract a cohomology computation. I imagine this is even more complicated for infinite discrete groups.